# What are the minimum unix permissions to run an executable jar file?

Tags: java, unix, permissions

If I have a jar that I need to run using `java -jar FOO.jar` on unix, does this depend on the read, write or execute bit? Or some combination thereof?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You just need read on the `.jar`, since `java` is what you're executing, and it reads the jar.

Comment: And execute permissions on the directories comprising the path.

Answer (score 4):

You will need `read`, since the jar is virtually executed by java (of course java needs to have `exec` permissions). But if you have a program that stores some data inside itself (it can happen, for example storing settings) I would suggest to have also the `write` attribute set.